# Javascript E4X - Return the text of node and its children?

Tags: javascript, e4x

I'm trying to parse some of html where there is are repeating lines of code such as:

```
<a>This is <span>some text</span> but its <span>not grabbing the span</span> content</a>
```

So I am looping through the object and extracting this:

```
object.a[i].text();
```

but its only returning

```
"This is  but its  content"
```

How do I grab the text within the children nodes as well, all as one string?

Cheers

Comment: the <span> is inside of the object <a> so you need to loop through its children as well.  Since you didn't really give details of how you are doing the loop it is hard to help you... are you using jquery?

Comment: its actually javascript inside a yahoo open data table. yahoo returns an E4X object and im just looping with a js for loop for the length of the number of "a" tags returned. If there is no easy way to get E4X to return the lot - how do i loop through the children and keep the text string in order? Edit: No jQuery available

Comment: @Chris From what I read on MDN, E4X is pretty much deprecated. If Yahoo is returning a string representing XML data, you should be able to parse it with jQuery, or similar libraries... So (in jQuery)...... `$( responseXML ).find( 'a' )...`

Comment: check out the very bottom of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X) page... it has some kind of loop for children... I'm not sure if it will still grab your text though or just the text in the spans... might take some messing around with it.

Comment: @Šime Thanks, I wouldn't usually use it client-side, but queries in Yahoo data tables return the data as E4X and the javascript is running serverside, so no jquery/libraries available =(

Comment: @M. Laing thanks, i think that child loop wouldn't be able to deliver the child text in order with the parent text though - However, that page did lead me to the .toXMLString() method - so if it comes down to it, i can push it out as a string and then replace the <span> with regex - still looking for a more elegant solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know E4X, but may I assume pure JavaScript is alright?

`textContent` [doesn't seem to have great compatibility for IE prior to version 9](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html).  This works when  `textContent` is available.  However I do not have IE8 so I cannot test with it, but this should work as well.

```
var obj = (!object.a[i].innerText) ? object.a[i].textContent : object.a[i].innerText;
```

---

That works in a client side implementation, but since it's not working in your implementation I guess you're going to need something more specific to your setup; unfortunately there's not much I can do there.  I will however give one more pure JS stab at it.  This iterates through each child node of object.a[i], determines if it is a textNode or elementNode and pulls data or innerHTML respectively.

```
var doesThisWork = '';
var children = object.a[i].childNodes;
for(x in children){
doesThisWork += (children[x].nodeType === 1) ? children[x].innerHTML : children[x].data;
}
```

---

I'll leave the jQuery version:

[.contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/):

```
object.a[i].contents().text();
```

Comment: thanks again Gary. This javascript is run serverside by yahoo so as long as they support it, should be all sweet. Unfortunately .textContent is returning nothing =( I have it working with a combination .toXMLString() and some dodgey regex to strip the tags right now. If anyone can come up with a more elegant solution i would be eternally grateful, but ill run with this for now. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: still returning nothing from any of those methods - but i assume that is just yahoos javascript shortfall - will mark the answer as correct for anyone searching for this in a general JS E4X environment. Thanks again.

Comment: I think I about have something work out with iterating over the children.  I'll update when I get it working.

Comment: The problem i was running into with grabbing the child text seperately is you couldnt get the "a" tags text up to/between each child seperately. So you would return "This is but its content some text not grabbing the span" instead of "This is some text but its  not grabbing the span  content" - if that makes any sense

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're able to return any text nodes that are direct children but not the contents of any child tags?

Comment: Correct. So in my example above object.a[i].text() returns "This is  but its  content", object.a[i].span[0].text() returns "some text", and object.a[i].span[1].text() returns "not grabbing the span" - i just cant arrange them in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

In Rhino this will work:

```html
var a = <a>This is <span>some text</span> but its <span>not grabbing <b>the</b> span</span> content</a>;
```

```js
print(XML_innerText(a));

function XML_innerText(node) {
    var result = [];
    for each (var i in node.descendants()) {
        if (i.nodeKind() == 'text') {
            result.push(i);
        }
    }
    return result.join(' ');
}
```

In more advanced variants of ecma/js you can use same code, but move it into XML.prototype.innerText and then calling something like `a.innerText()` directly.